# « Parler espagnol » ou « parler l'espagnol » ?

Tags: usage, articles

Je pense que j'ai lu que, quand on dit, par exemple,

> Louis parle anglais

ça veut dire que Louis est, maintenant, en train de parler anglais, ou peut-être qu'il le parle habituellement, comme dans :

> Louis et sa mère parlent anglais, mais Louis et son père parlent français.

Mais quand on dit au contraire

> Louis parle l'anglais

avec l'article défini, ça veut dire que Louis sait parler anglais. C'est vrai ? Si oui, pourquoi dit-on « parlez-vous français » et pas « parlez-vous le français » quand on veut savoir si une personne sait parler français ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On peut très bien dire « Louis parle anglais » pour signifier « Louis sait parler anglais ». Ma première réaction était que « Louis parle l'anglais » ne pourrait pas vouloir dire « Louis parle anglais en ce moment », mais réflexion faite je pense que ce n'est pas le cas et que ces deux formes sont complètement synonymes.

Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parler) ne fait pas de différence.

> Employer telle ou telle langue pour s'exprimer. *Parler argot, parler (l')anglais; parler plusieurs langues.*
>
> […] Rem. 1. Lorsque le compl. désigne une lang. déterminée, l'art. peut être supprimé (*supra ex.*).

« Parler l'anglais » est peut-être légèrement plus soutenu et vieilli, mais je ne suis pas sûr. J'ai tendance à omettre l'article, en tout cas, mais l'entendre ou le lire ne me choque pas.

Google Ngrams montre une préférence pour *[parle anglais](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parle+l%27anglais%2Cparle+anglais&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparle%20l%27%20anglais%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparle%20anglais%3B%2Cc0)*, pour *[parle russe](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parle+russe%2Cparle+le+russe&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparle%20russe%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparle%20le%20russe%3B%2Cc0)*, pour *[parle espagnol](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parle+espagnol%2Cparle+l%27espagnol&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparle%20espagnol%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparle%20l%27%20espagnol%3B%2Cc0)*, pour *[parle le chinois](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=parle+chinois%2Cparle+le+chinois&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cparle%20chinois%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cparle%20le%20chinois%3B%2Cc0)*, … Mais attention, le nombre d'occurrences est faible, et l'apostrophe n'est pas toujours numérisée correctement.

Comment: On peut noter que « parler chinois » peut signifier : s'exprimer de manière incompréhensible, contrairement à « parler le chinois ».

Answer (score 3):

L'article défini est requis si la langue a un complément :

> Louis parle l'anglais de Liverpool
>
> Mathis parle le français de France.