# Différences entre "Je parle la <langue>" ou "je parle <langue>"

Tags: sens, articles

Un ami apprenant le français m'a posé une question sur la différence entre

> Je parle italien

et

> Je parle l'italien

Ma première explication était: (je lui ai dit que j'allais quand même poser la question :))

- *Je parle italien* peut avoir deux significations:

  - que je parle italien "maintenant" (quelqu'un n'a pas reconnu la langue et me demande laquelle c'est)
  - ou que je connais l'italien et que je peux le parler/comprendre
- *Je parle l'italien* signifie seulement que je connais l'italien et que je peux le parler/comprendre

**Question 1**: est-ce que mon impression est formellement correcte?

**Question 2**: quid de la situation où un Français dirait *"Je parle **le** français"* → cela sonne pas trop bien (à mon avis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oui, je suis d'accord avec tes explications.

- ***Parler en français*** signifie s'exprimer (en ce moment) en français.
- ***Parler le français*** signifie savoir s'exprimer oralement en français.
- ***Parler français*** peut avoir l'un ou l'autre de ces deux sens.

Référence, *Le bon usage, 14e édition*, Grevisse et Goose, 2007 :

> Parler le français exprime plutôt une virtualité ; c'est être capable d'utiliser cette langue : *Il parle aussi bien le français que l'anglais*. Parler en français concerne une réalisation précise : *Le président a parlé en anglais*. — On distingue de la même façon : *Il écrit le français*. *Il a écrit en français*. — Mais parler a une autre possibilité, qui est refusée à écrire : *parler français*. Cette dernière expression peut avoir les deux nuances distinguées ci-dessus.

Voir aussi: [« Parler espagnol » ou « parler l'espagnol » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9700/parler-espagnol-ou-parler-lespagnol)

Comment: Merci - j'ai clos ma question en tant que duplicate (de celle dans ton lien)

Comment: **En dehors de tout contexte** « je parle français » et « je parle le français » ont le même sens et les deux sont corrects,  « je parle français » est de loin le plus courant. Je suis d'accord avec ce que dit cette enseignante de FLE https://nathaliefle.com/parler-francais-preposition-article/. Grevisse,  § 378, 10e édition fait une remarque intéressante sur la valeur adverbiale du nom dans *je parle français*. Et  voir un développement sur la nuance entre les 2 p. 400 de la version électronique que je n'ai pas mais que tu trouveras en ligne.

Comment: @None Oui, la vidéo est très pédagogique et explique bien les multiples cas d'usage. Pour répondre à ta première affirmation, je trouve que *je parle le français* n'a pas toujours le même sens que *je parle français* car, comme WoJ, je ne m'attends pas à ce que quelqu'un le dise simplement pour exprimer le fait qu'il parle français à ce moment là. La présence de l'article réduit pour moi les contextes possibles donc *je parle le français* ne peut pas exister indépendamment de tout contexte. Je vais regarder ce que Grevisse nous dit là-dessus.

Comment: @None *Il écrit le français* (lbu) me semble un peu daté.